# Laravel won't link stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2.

I have `public/app.css` and i link it from `views/layouts/app.blade.php` with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path('app.css') }}">
```

I have tried every combination that i can think of, like using `asset()` `asset_path()`, putting `app.css` in `views/layouts/` with the app.blade.php file and nothing will work.

If I inspect the source of a page, it shows the link and the path is correct, but the styles won't apply.

Comment: Echoing out `public_path('app.css')` somewhere should quickly illuminate why it's the wrong function to use. Path != URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('app.css') }}">
```

Comment: I've tried that before, but for some reason it actually worked this time. Thanks, and sorry for the beginner question. SO will let me accept you answer as correct in 12 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<link href="{!! asset('css/app.css') !!}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```